# MotionEvent.ACTION_UP event is fired twice with seekbar

Tags: android, motionevent, android-vertical-seekbar

The onStopTrackingTouch event is fired twice and that's a problem cause I just need to make a getRequest. Here is my code:

VerticalSeekbar.java

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

if (!isEnabled()) {
    return false;
}
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
            int progress = getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight());
            // Ensure progress stays within boundaries
            if(progress < 0) {progress = 0;}
            if(progress > getMax()) {
                progress = getMax();}
            setProgress(progress);  // Draw progress
            if(progress != lastProgress) {
                // Only enact listener if the progress has actually changed
                lastProgress = progress;
                Information.onSeekBarChangeListener.onProgressChanged(this, progress, true);
            }
            onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight() , 0, 0);
            Log.i("radio", "action move");
            setPressed(true);
            setSelected(true);
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.i("radio", "action up"); //printed twice
            Information.onSeekBarChangeListener.onStopTrackingTouch(this);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Information.java

```
onSeekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
            radio = (progress / (double) 10);
            tv_radio.setText(radio + " Km");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){
            Log.i("vertical", "onStart");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){
            Log.i("vertical", "onStopTracking"); //printed twice
            getRequest request = new getRequest();
            request.execute("http://...");
        }
    };
    sb_radio.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(onSeekBarChangeListener);
```

Any idea why `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is detected twice? Even if I just do a simple click in the `Seekbar` without dragging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TouchListener will be called for every `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, and `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`

so the problem is, There is a `break` statement is missing after `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` so even when you fall under `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` case the control will keeps on executing the further case until some stop point reached, like `break` etc

```
   switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
            int progress = getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight());
            if(progress < 0) {progress = 0;}
            if(progress > getMax()) {
                progress = getMax();}
            setProgress(progress);  
            if(progress != lastProgress) {
                lastProgress = progress;
                Information.onSeekBarChangeListener.onProgressChanged(this, progress, true);
            }
            onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight() , 0, 0);
            Log.i("radio", "action move");
            setPressed(true);
            setSelected(true);
            break;         // add a break statement here and problem solved
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.i("radio", "action up"); 
            Information.onSeekBarChangeListener.onStopTrackingTouch(this);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```